# Не отрабатывает анимация на кнопке, если добавлять программно

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

Есть следующий метод:

```
public void AddFocusEffect(AnimationClip focusClip, GameObject[] focusElements)
    {
        // AnimationClip focus = Resources.Load("Focus", typeof(AnimationClip)) as AnimationClip;

        foreach (GameObject focusElement in focusElements)
        {
            focusElement.AddComponent<Outline>();
            Animation anim = focusElement.AddComponent<Animation>();
            anim.clip = focusClip;
        }
    }
```

focusClip вешается через инспектор (потому что закомментированный код почему-то не отрабатывает), и в итоге все компоненты правильно создаются и выглядит так, как если бы мы добавили и поправили их сами, но не срабатывают (в отличие от обычного случая).

Почему может быть такое поведение?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Компонент [Animation является устаревшим](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-Animation.html) уже довольно давно и в более новых версиях его собираются выпилить.

Вместо него лучше использовать схему с [Animator](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Animator.html), а мелкие анимации реализовывать через корутины или различные твины.

По сути вопроса: добавьте после назначения клипа строчку `anim.Play();`
Автоматическое воспроизведение работает только, если на момент Start() там есть клип.

Comment: Да, с этой функцией сработало - правда, пришлось еще добавить `anim.AddClip(focusClip, "Focus");`. Спасибо за подробный комментарий!